# Inserting "$" in a SELECT Statement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `SELECT` Statement that shows details on Orders.

It uses the below code

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.invoiceID, Items.itemName AS 'Item Name', Orders.quantity, DATENAME(mm, Orders.OrderDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(dd, Orders.OrderDate) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy, Orders.OrderDate) AS 'Order Date', (Orders.price * Orders.quantity) AS 'Total', Orders.delivered
    FROM Orders
    INNER JOIN Items
    ON Orders.itemID = Items.itemID
    ORDER BY Orders.orderID, Items.itemID ASC
```

Everything works fine, however I'm not sure how to get a "$" to show up to the left of the numbers in the "total" field.

All help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: Formatting is the display layer's job (app, report, etc).  Adding formatting to numeric values in SQL prevents you from treating them as numbers in other layers (to sum, average, compare, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, 
       Orders.invoiceID, 
       Items.itemName AS 'Item Name', 
       Orders.quantity, 
       DATENAME(mm, Orders.OrderDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(dd, Orders.OrderDate) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy, Orders.OrderDate) AS 'Order Date', 
       '$' + Convert(VARCHAR(50), Orders.price * Orders.quantity) AS 'Total', 
       Orders.delivered
FROM   Orders
INNER JOIN Items ON Orders.itemID = Items.itemID
ORDER BY   Orders.orderID, Items.itemID ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just explicitly concat it:

```
SELECT     Orders.OrderID, 
           Orders.invoiceID, 
           Items.itemName AS 'Item Name', 
           Orders.quantity, 
           DATENAME(mm, Orders.OrderDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(dd, Orders.OrderDate) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy, Orders.OrderDate) AS 'Order Date', 
           '$' + (CAST (Orders.price * Orders.quantity) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS 'Total', 
           Orders.delivered
FROM       Orders
INNER JOIN Items ON Orders.itemID = Items.itemID
ORDER BY   Orders.orderID, Items.itemID ASC
```

Comment: Note: depending on the language that this is written in, you may need to escape the `$`.

Comment: I would have casted this as varchar, is that not necessary? 
@AMADANONInc.- It's SQL Server so it's fine here.

Comment: I thought that would work earlier, Unfortunatly it did not. still just the numbers. Perhaps CASTING would be in order?

Comment: Got it, had to use CASTING. Thanks Guys.

Comment: @Bryan D yep, so '$' + cast(your values) as varchar(10)) AS 'Total' .  You can also use char(36) in place of the $, but I doubt you need to.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but this is the same answer but casting the numeric value.

```
SELECT     Orders.OrderID, 
           Orders.invoiceID, 
           Items.itemName AS 'Item Name', 
           Orders.quantity, 
    DATENAME(mm, Orders.OrderDate) + ' ' + DATENAME(dd, Orders.OrderDate) + ', ' + DATENAME(yyyy,          Orders.OrderDate) AS 'Order Date', 
    '$' + CAST((Orders.price * Orders.quantity) as varchar(90))
          AS 'Total', 
           Orders.delivered
FROM       Orders
INNER JOIN Items ON Orders.itemID = Items.itemID
ORDER BY   Orders.orderID, Items.itemID ASC
```